# Tried to install topoJSON and got this

Tags: topojson

Caseys-MacBook-Pro:~ casey$ npm install -g topojson

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/topojson

npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/topojson

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/topojson/-/topojson-1.1.4.tgz

npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/topojson/-/topojson-1.1.4.tgz

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson'

npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson']

npm ERR!   errno: 3,

npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson',

npm ERR!   fstream_type: 'Directory',

npm ERR!   fstream_path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson',

npm ERR!   fstream_class: 'DirWriter',

npm ERR!   fstream_stack:

npm ERR!    [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23',

npm ERR!      '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53',

npm ERR!      'Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)' ] }

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.4.0

npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "topojson"

npm ERR! cwd /Users/casey

npm ERR! node -v v0.10.11

npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.30

npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson

npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson

npm ERR! fstream_type Directory

npm ERR! fstream_class DirWriter

npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! errno 3

npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/topojson'

npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/dir-writer.js:36:23

npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53

npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)

npm ERR!

npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:

npm ERR!     /Users/casey/npm-debug.log

npm ERR! not ok code 0

I have no idea what to do or how to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

I think that I fixed by using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I also fixed it by

```
sudo npm install -g topojson
```

All the process were then successful.

Afterwhat my

```
topojson -o output.json input.shp
```

however, didn't worked.

**Did topojson worked fine after your sudo install ?**

Comment: if you run: which topojson in terminal and it gives back: /usr/local/bin/topojson then the installation is fine, whatch out for the directories of the files you use!

Comment: yeah I guessed that when I saw the date of the post, after I submitted the comment! Glad you resolved it and I also saw your blocks, really cool